# how to setup different languages in magento 2.1.6 version

Tags: magento-2.1, language

I have a doubt regarding language setup. My default language is ENGLISH and I need to add ARABIC language along with ENGLISH.When we click on ARABIC language same store view with the same theme will be translated to ARABIC from ENGLISH.

Firstly I created Arabic Store view in the admin panel. And theme will be selected for particular store view in the edit of language store view. What is the next process?

Will you please send me any idea and the way to setup language?

Answer (score 0):

You need to install arabic language pack

You can get more inforamtion about installation and how to use from here

[magento-2-arabic-language-pack](https://github.com/mageplaza/magento-2-arabic-language-pack)

Let me know if you have any issue.